# What metals/materials can't a lightsaber cut through?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

We know a lightsaber can't cut through everything in the Star Wars universe, but I would like to know all known metals/materials that a lightsaber can't cut through (in the sense can't cut in two halves or at least penetrate it). For the sake of convenience I am reducing the answers to the live action movies/tv-shows and legends comics only.

I am not asking whether there is something lighsabres cant cut, I know there are many things a lighsabre cant cut, what I am asking is the names of all known metal/materials it cant cut thorugh.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Lightsaber-resistant_materials

Comment: Fyi This site doesn't allow list questions

Comment: [Finite well scoped list questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2638/58193) are on topic, this would seem to fall into that category so should be fine.

Comment: i am not asking for whether it can or cant, i know it cant cut everything, i am asking for all known metals it cant cut

Comment: The dupe already addresses that, hence why this got closed